# Problem parenting mesh with armature

Tags: animation, mesh, parent

I create my mesh with the sculpting mode and now that I want to parent it with my armature, I get strange strips on my mesh.

Before parenting, I set the armature in rest mode.

I cant see these strips in rest mode, but when I start the animation or I simply set the pose mode I can see them.

The problem are not the animations, they work perfectly with the mesh!

The problem are these strips that "deform" my mesh.

I tried the program *Instant Mesh* to lower the number of faces of my mesh, but the same problem remains.

[Blend File](https://easyupload.io/22e26p)

[image: Rest Mode, no strips][image: Pose Mode-Animation, strips]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Questions like these can always benefit from a look at your mesh topology.  Include a shot of your mesh in edit mode.  Also, what kind of parenting did you do?  See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/skinning/parenting.html

Comment: I tried all the 3 types of parenting, but the problem persists

Comment: here a video to show you what happens https://streamable.com/599thq

Comment: here my blender file, if someone has time to take a look https://easyupload.io/22e26p

Comment: sorry, but your blend file isn't rigged. It's a mesh and a rig. So please upload a file which corresponds to your screenshots.

Comment: your mesh is much too high-poly for animation! You should work with a low-poly version, unless you have a good reason?

Comment: The file is the same of the photos, you have to parent the mesh and the rig...I tried to lower the definition of my mesh using "Instant Mesh", but the problem persists... With how many faces can I consider my mesh like a "low-poly"?

Comment: Base models have usually around 10k-40k verts. These models can be used for game engines. For the final render, a *Subdivision Surface* modifier can be added to smooth out the shape. This can bump the vertex count up to 140k. You need to retopologize your model. Details from hi-poly sculpts can be baked into a normal map and used for the low-poly version. You also can use a premade low-poly base mesh and sculpt it to bring it into the shape you like. Then add a *MultRes* modifier to sculpt more details and bake them. Remove the modifier and you will have the low-poly version again.